# adding hg after svn and pushing

Tags: svn, mercurial

We used to have the production site under SVN control. We are now working in mercurial with bitbucket.

So what I have locally is a folder where there is both a .svn and a .hg directory.

But what I want to do is:

- Remove svn control from the local folder
- Stay on mercurial
- Still be able to push changes to SVN on the server.

Could can I do this?

Comment: If you want to use SVN you need the `.svn` folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would strongly recommend against having both Mercurial and Subversion VCS. Aside doubling administration time for management different VCS, it mostly negates any benefits of using Mercurial in a first place.

I have been through similar path before - working locally in Mercurial whilst officially there was only SVN repo. Well, I got used to flattening revision history to get in more digestible by Subversion but I was not anything close to pleasant experience.

Once we eliminated Subversion out of the equation my life started to be significantly happier.

Probably with small projects the pain in not that noticeable but having co-existing source control system just add up unnecessary development workflow steps I would avoided.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of choices when you want to work with subversion listed [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion).

I've used `hgsubversion` and it is quite restrictive in that it needs you to work in such a way that SVN will be able to cope with. It means that you need to use `hg rebase` a lot and it might be tricky to manage in a team - particularly if not all of the team will be pushing to SVN.

I've not used MQ to interface with SVN so I can't comment on how easy that might be.

Comment: To be more specific, you easily get in deep troubles if you don't use the svn repository as the code exchange repository, since this creates the possibility that someone pushes merge commits there. I already described how to flatten these merges in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5338918/311635, but this way is almost impossible if these merges are already published somewhere.